# Android: How to debug core apps like Settings

Tags: android, command-line

How do I build and debug the cores apps in Android source tree, like AlarmClock and Settings, located under:
`${ROOT}/packages/apps`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You follow the instructions for working with the platform source code, such as [how to obtain the source](http://source.android.com/source/download.html) and [how to set up Eclipse for Android platform development](http://source.android.com/source/using-eclipse.html).